# gsoap: Specify schema type for optional element xsd:anyType

Tags: c++, client, gsoap

I am trying to login to a webservice using the following code:

```
_ns1__Login log;
log.soap = proxy.soap;
log.systemname = &loginData.systemName[0];
log.username = &loginData.username[0];
log.Password = &loginData.password[0];
log.timeout = loginData.timeout;


_ns1__LoginResponse loginResp;
loginResp.soap = proxy.soap;
auto status = proxy.Login(&log, loginResp);
```

```
log.systemname = &loginData.systemName[0];
log.username = &loginData.username[0];
log.Password = &loginData.password[0];
```

These are all of value: char* because they are defined as xsd::anyType. I want to specify in the request sent that they are of type xsd::string. What am I missing?

Thanks.